# Using Python to plot points on a World Map

Tags: python, plot

I want to make a earthquake world map app that pulls data from a us.gov text file and displays one earthquake at a time on the map as a dot. I know how to pull and parse the data, but I'm struggling with how to actually plot the points on the map. Can anyone tell me how they would do this with Python? I've done it with Java before by using an imported class called Zen.Java, is there an equivalent for Python?

Comment: possibly gmplot could be of use here, https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at matplotlib basemap
http://matplotlib.org/basemap/

and examples here
http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html

Comment: Is matplotlib abandonware? There doesn't seem to have been any development on it for the past 12 months?

Comment: Nope, last commit was 3 days ago https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib

Comment: It's using outdated matplotlib code which requires editing to work. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50928480/2523501

Answer (score 11):

Try pyGal. Its a nice lib for python, with many features. http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/maps/pygal_maps_world.html