# 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_axis_bgcolor'

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to run Basemap examples from [here](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geography.html) and I am facing an error 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_axis_bgcolor'. When I try first example from the site I should receive contours black, water blue and land coral, but in my case boundaries are black but both water and land are blue

I am using:
-Python 3.5.5
-Matplotlib 2.2.2

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please be specific, there are several examples there. Which one did you use?

Comment: Which version of Basemap are you using? Which code is run to produce this error? Provide the full error traceback instead of the last line.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue and solved it - see answer below.

Answer (score 11):

`Basemap` (even current latest version 1.0.7) is using deprecated `Matplotlib` command (see: [matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/…](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axis_bgcolor.html)). This command **`ax.get_axis_bgcolor()`** needs to be replaced by `ax.get_fc()` in the file `__init__.py` found in the `...\lib\pythonX.X\site-packaged\mpl_toolkits\basemap` directory.

There are instances in the following two functions **`drawmapboundary()`** and **`fillcontinents()`**.

Save the edits, then re-start and run the python script.

Comment: `ax.ishold()` is another deprecated `matplotlib` function which `baseplot` uses (though this one doesn't break the script).

Comment: Worked great, also to use with Python3 all the print commands in the __init__.py  must use parentheses .

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `set_axis_bgcolor` with `set_facecolor`